# PHP : inject javascript code inside the html file

Tags: javascript, php, dom

i want to write/inject a javascript code inside a html file "template.html".

```
<div id="scr">

</div>
```

and javascript is

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){}
</script>
```

PHP

```
        $doc = new DOMDocument();

        $doc->loadHTMLFile("template.html");

        $doc->getElementById('scr')->nodeValue="<script>window.onload = function(){}</script>"; 

        $doc->saveHTMLFile("html/".$name.".html");
```

What i am getting is

```
<div id="scr">&lt;script&gt;window.onload = function(){}&lt;/script&gt;</div>
```

What i am expecting:

```
<div id="scr"><script>window.onload = function(){}</script></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using htmlentities() ?

Comment: Because I have not used this myself I don't want to give an answer, but from what I read on this it seems you want to append a child element to add a tag. 


It is quite obvious that nodeValue here treats the string as what to show on the page and therefor escapes the "<" and ">".


I suspect you would want to use appendChild. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php

Comment: i tried the createChild and appendChild and this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a method `setInnerHTML`

```
function setInnerHTML($element, $html)
{
    $fragment = $element->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML($html);
    $clone = $element->cloneNode(); // Get element copy without children
    $clone->appendChild($fragment);
    $element->parentNode->replaceChild($clone, $element);
}

//your code

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTMLFile("template.html");

setInnerHTML($doc->getElementById('scr'),"<script>window.onload = function(){}</script>"); 

$doc->saveHTMLFile("html/".$name.".html");
```

this will work like a charm and so generic to use too...

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

        $doc->loadHTMLFile("template.html");

        $script=$doc->createElement("script");

        $script->nodeValue="window.onload = function(){}";

        $doc->getElementById('scr')->appendChild($script);

        $doc->saveHTMLFile("html/".$name.".html");
```